# data exchange from loopback to jhipster

Tags: reactjs, jhipster, loopback4

I use loopback 4 for backend and jhipster with react and redux for frontend. Up to now I have used the entity to send the data to the client, but in this way the frontend  have much more responsibility and have to handle much more data than it need to handle. I was thinking of using DTOs, but I have to create several (eg dto for the result list and another one for edit/show form). I could create as frontend two reducer, one for list and one for show/edit form.

What do you think? is this a correct approach?

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me, what is the architecture? 
Do you mean that you don't use JHipster as backend? When you say client you mean frontend? Also, your proposed modes are not clear either. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I agree to @GaëlMarziou . Question is not very clear. Can you elaborate if you want to avoid jhipster or something else ?